# Reducing the height of Vuetify dropdown

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am not able to reduce the height of the Vuetify dropdown component `v-select`. I tried using the props `dense` but it only reduces the height of the options to select and doesn't show any effect on the closed dropdown.

I tried the following template code:

```
<v-select :items="selectableYears" dense outlined></v-select>
```

The example code from the documenation is very similar:

```
<v-select
    :items="items"
    label="Outlined style"
    dense
    outlined
></v-select>
```

Documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like that the dense props is only partially available with the Vuetify version I used (2.0.5). Upgrading the version to 2.1.0 reduces the height of the closed dropdown when using `:dense="true"` as a prop.

Answer (score 3):

In order to adjust the Vuetify dropdown height, you must use the `height` API. As follow:

```
<v-select
  :items="items"
  label="Standard"
  height="300px" // Height API
></v-select>
```

If you want to reduce it to lesser than the default, try to write css class for `.v-text-field.v-text-field--solo .v-input__control`, which is the wrapper of `v-select`.

```
.v-text-field.v-text-field--solo .v-input__control{
    min-height: 30px;
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/fsaadatpei/pen/XWrvEGR

Comment: Yes it works to increase the height. However it doesn't help me with reducing the height.

Comment: `.v-input__slot {
    min-height: 30px !important;
  }` allows me to reduce the height a little bit

Comment: Use `.v-text-field.v-text-field--solo .v-input__control`. updated the answer. @SimonThiel

Comment: You can also mess with the `.v-label` and a wrapper around that.

Comment: This solution works for solo, what is the selector for outlined? I can't seem to figure that one out.