# Resizing of v-combobox with delete icon

Tags: vue.js, combobox, styles, vuetify.js

I have a v-combobox that I need to resize. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58202911/reducing-the-height-of-vuetify-dropdown) works pretty well, but I have a problem with delete icon in combobox:

[image]

How can I solve it?
Here is combobox code and styling

```
      <v-combobox
        outlined
        clearable
      ></v-combobox>

  .v-text-field .v-input__control .v-input__slot {
    min-height: 30px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<style>
  .v-text-field .v-input__control .v-input__slot {
    min-height: 30px;
  }
  .v-text-field.v-text-field--enclosed .v-input__prepend-outer, .v-text-field
  .v-text-field--enclosed .v-input__prepend-inner, .v-text-field.v-text-field--enclosed
  .v-input__append-inner, .v-text-field.v-text-field--enclosed .v-input__append-outer {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
</style>
```